# VBA: pdf file close immediately after open

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm curerntly create a button to open PDF file from a product name. To be more specific, you chose 1 cell, then click on the button, it will open the PDF file in folder.
If i open a pdf file by double click on it, everything is fine.
But the problem is when i use VBA to open, my pdf file close immediately after it open

Here is my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim filename As Variant
filename = ActiveCell.Value

'If cell is empty, it don't open nothing
If filename = "" Then
   Exit Sub
Else
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("Y:\0302_Logistics\MRP\20.TDS-MSDS\" & filename & ".pdf")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did a quick test, unable to reproduce (my PDF opened up fine and did not close by itself).

Comment: What is happening when you try opening it manually? Maybe it is a problem with the application which opens it. In which application is it open? Do you have Acrobat Reader installed?

Comment: @FaneDuru everything is normal when i try to opening it manually. I use Acrobat Reader to open it

Comment: @DongKha When the macro opens the PDF, is it in Acrobat Reader as well?